# How to append missing values from a list in sequential order?

Tags: python-3.x

Example my 2 list are.

```
a = [11,22]
b = [33,22,11,44,55]
```

My expected output should add missing values from b into a in a sequential order.

```
a = [11,22,33,44,55]
```

This is my codes to achieve the output

```
z = (set(b).difference(a))
y = list(z)
for i in y:
    a.append(i)
```

However if I print(y) it is [33,55,44], why is it not returning [33,44,55]?
and how do i achieve my desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [11,22]
b = [33,22,11,44,55]

c = list(set(a+b))
c.sort()
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not adding in sequential order because you are using `set` and the output can be different every try. You can use list comprehension to achieve this goal.

```
a = [11,22]
b = [33,22,11,44,55]
a += [element for element in b if element not in a]
```

Comment: what if i add in a new list c = [11,22,33,44,55] and after comparison with b. I want to make 'a' back to the original size of [11,22] and then add the missing values from c into a. how would i format the codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set()` method to sort `z`.
**Corrected code :-**

```
a = [11,22] 
b = [33,22,11,44,55]
z = set((set(b).difference(a)))
y = list(z) 
for i in y: 
    a.append(i)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [11,22]
b = [33,22,11,44,55]
for item in set(b):
   if item not in a:
      a.append(item)
print(a)
```

Loop through each element of second list(b), add in list(a) if element is not present